# Select fields based on multiple ids mysql

Tags: mysql

There are two tables
Table 1

id --------- name

10001        Abc

10002        Xyz

Table 2

fromid   ------ toid ------ message

10001           10002       Hi

I want the result to be as

name ----- name1 ------ message

Abc        Xyz          Hi

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.name as name, t2.name as name1, t3.message
from table2 as t3
join table1 as t2 on t3.fromid = t2.id
join table1 as t1 on t3.toid = t1.id
```

I think this will fulfill your question.